# why would you want export private key?

Tags: ssl-certificate

Why would anyone want to export SSL private key?

Comment: Not a programming question, though.

Comment: @Status: I think it is, e.g. if you need to create your own SSL certificates for development, testing, staging etc.

Comment: @mousio: so any OS-related question would be, too? Because you need an OS to run your development tools? :)

Comment: @Status: and for programming I need internet stuff also (cables, appliances, applications) e.g. to access SO :]

Comment: Move to [WM](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @mousio: takes more to flag, I guess ;)

Answer (score 2):

for importing it onto another machine?